# Flutter firebase deprecated api, can't build appbundle in release

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, compiler-errors, google-play

I wanted to publish my app to the Google Play Store but when I try to compile my App, I get this error, does any one knows how to solve it ?

```
flutter build appbundle --release
```

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /Users/myName/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-5.0.9/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/myName/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.3+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/myName/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.0+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
```

Comment: Thats not an error, just a warning. The appbundle is created equally

Comment: Oh ok, I had a bug and I thought it came from this message but I found out what it was, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a warning, not an error. I had a bug and I thought it came from this message but I found out what it was.